# RabbitMQ synchronous message processing with asynchronous two queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Using RabbitMQ with Java Spring, is it possible to perform a synchronous wait to ensure that a message sent to the first queue is added to the second queue after being processed by an external service and then the result from the second queue is received and used via the same thread?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `@RabbitListner` is able to receive and reply with support of `@SendTo`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/async-annotation-driven/reply.html

The `RabbitTempalte` has an API like `sendAndReceive()` to perform request-reply synchronous operations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/request-reply.html

So, let's see if that helps you somehow!